# Align bars to the start of Bar chart (amcharts 4)

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have 2 bar charts that are placed next to each other.

[image]

The left one has 7 bars and the right one has only 6 bars yet these 6 bars utilize all chart's height.
Is it possible somehow to place bars at the start leaving chart's grid with a full height? Something like `align-items: start`?